# How would I change the contents of an HTML class using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a grade holder project and I have an html class that holds one of the grades.

```html
<span class="tooltip">
              <span class="grade">83.49%</span>
            </span>
```

I wanted to know how I could use JavaScript to turn the 83.49 into a 90.

I tried using the getElementsByClass but I wasn't actually sure of how to go about setting it up. All I need to do is change the specific grade.

Comment: I don't even know how to go about solving my problem which is why I am asking for help. But I went ahead and edited it with some more info.

Answer (score 1):

if you have used grade class only at this place you can use this solution :- 

`document.getElementsByClassName("grade")[0].innerText = "90";`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('grade')[0].innerText = '90%';
```

Note: `getElementsByClassName` returns array-like collection of elements.

Comment: I get a error telling me that getElementsByClass is not defined. Any way I can go about changing that?

Comment: @RayRazak use `document.getElementsByClass`

Comment: You forgot `document`

Comment: And `getElementByClassName`.

Comment: @MaximAnatol'evichBorovsky nah, it's indeed Element**s**

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector()`:

```js
 

document.querySelector(".tooltip .grade").innerText = "90%";
```

```html
 

<span class="tooltip">
<span class="grade">83.49%</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)(is round the number to higher value) .Use this `(num/10)*10` formula to convert the number round of `10`

1. First replace the `%` value form text.
2. Then parse the string to number using `parseFloat()`
3. Then apply above formula

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.grade');
Array.from(elem,(a,b)=>{
var str = a.textContent.replace('%', '').trim();
a.textContent = Math.ceil(parseFloat(str) / 10) * 10+'%';
})
```

```html
<span class="tooltip">
   <span class="grade">83.49%</span>
   <span class="grade">83.49%</span>
   <span class="grade">43.49%</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use separate ids for elements to call them by id as follows;

```js
function cha()
{
  ele=document.getElementById("grade");
  ele.innerHTML="90%";
}
```

```html
<span class="tooltip">
     <span id="grade">83.49%</span>
</span>
<button onclick="cha()">Change</button>
```

**Edit:** If you still want to use classes then you can use 0th index of  class array you got by using `getElementsByClassName` follows;

```js
    function cha()
    {
      ele=document.getElementsByClassName("grade");
      ele[0].innerHTML="90%";
    }
```

```html
    <span class="tooltip">
         <span class="grade">83.49%</span>
    </span>
    <button onclick="cha()">Change</button>
```